# Can not install async-sqlalchemy on Mac (fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found #include "Python.h")

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, asyncpg

I am trying to install `async-sqlalchemy` in virtual environment but get an error during the installation of `asyncpg` package.

I have reinstalled python, made homebrew upgrade, but it did not helped.

**Other inputs:**

- macOS Monterey 12.4
- Apple M1 Max
- python was installed using homebrew
- headers location: `/opt/homebrew/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers/Python.h`
- Python 3.8.9 installed in virtual environment

**Text of error:**

```
(venv) ➜  project1 git:(main) ✗ pip install async-sqlalchemy

pip install async-sqlalchemy
Collecting async-sqlalchemy
  Using cached async_sqlalchemy-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 kB)
Collecting sqlalchemy
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.4.40.tar.gz (8.3 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting asyncpg
  Using cached asyncpg-0.26.0.tar.gz (809 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting aiomysql
  Using cached aiomysql-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
Collecting PyMySQL>=1.0
  Using cached PyMySQL-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: asyncpg, sqlalchemy
  Building wheel for asyncpg (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for asyncpg (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext
      building 'asyncpg.pgproto.pgproto' extension
      asyncpg/pgproto/pgproto.c:31:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
      #include "Python.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for asyncpg
  Building wheel for sqlalchemy (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for sqlalchemy: filename=SQLAlchemy-1.4.40-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_14_arm64.whl size=1563095 sha256=dec89820eeaacf37173105593f3bd9762e66d86bec9d058b6e16a2a6b0905467
  Stored in directory: /Users/[user_name deleted_intentionally]/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/b6/24/79/b40cf000cb96fbda45242a556ce18006f8ca34712487c09a90
Successfully built sqlalchemy
Failed to build asyncpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and had a lot of research. Finally found the problem in my other python project

> source venv/bin/activate

was active. So I have deactivated from another project and then re-run the installation again.

Comment: Thank you! it really helped! I spent 2-3 days for research, thank you for this solution!

Comment: Same here. deactivate and activate works! thanks!